UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: empty/missing DT_HASH/DT_GNU_HASH
I'm trying to build and run a sample app on an emulator with Android 15 with support for 16KB page sizes.
At the start of the app, when initializing the realm library, I'm getting the following error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: empty/missing DT_HASH/DT_GNU_HASH in "/data/data/com.testapp.qa/app_lib/librealm-jni.so.10.18.0" (new hash type from the future?)                                                               at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:933)                                                                at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1729)                      at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.SystemLibraryLoader.loadPath(SystemLibraryLoader.java:29)               at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinkerInstance.loadLibraryInternal(ReLinkerInstance.java:204)                     at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinkerInstance.loadLibrary(ReLinkerInstance.java:136)                                         at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinker.loadLibrary(ReLinker.java:70)                                      at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinker.loadLibrary(ReLinker.java:57)                                      at io.realm.internal.RealmCore.loadLibrary(RealmCore.java:60)                                                       at io.realm.Realm.initializeRealm(Realm.java:348)                                                               at io.realm.Realm.init(Realm.java:263)
I've used Android NDK r27 with
externalNativeBuild { cmake { arguments "-DANDROID_SUPPORT_FLEXIBLE_PAGE_SIZES=ON" } }

It appears some steps were missed during the setup and install process. Please review the Realm Getting Started Guide

The setup and install process was correct, because it works for other Android versions, except for Android 15 with 16KB page sizes https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/page-sizes

So what does this have to do with Realm, as tagged in the question? Do have some Realm code that's not working that we can help with?

This seems like a setup or config issue. This question should not be here

@vjimbei I have same error ? Did you get any workaround ?

@BULLA not yet. I understand the library should be rebuilt with some extra options to support this new 16 KB page size. I didn't have time to download the sources and rebuild the realm locally.

@vjimbei Me too. Just one confutation is that all of device update to Android 15 will be crashed ? Or only Android device release from this year ( of course with set of Android 15) will be crashed ?

They are not going to activate 16KB page size by default on Android 15. It will be available as a developer option in Developer Settings in select devices (for now we know about Pixel 8 and 9).
